# Ubuntu grub bootloader problem

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grubrescue, grub-efi

I was dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 side by side, everything worked well. Since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, it got Ubuntu bash on Windows, so I thought to uninstall Ubuntu and directly deleted the partition in which Ubuntu was installed..

Now I can't even get the option to boot Windows 10 either. No option is shown, it just  says:

> `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.`

And I am given the command line in this way:

```
 grub>
```

Further information I don't have any rescue disk or any Windows 10 installation media.. Windows 10 Home was by default loaded into it. Also this PC doesn't have DVD ROM.

Comment: Do you have a spare USB to create a bootable Ubuntu?

Comment: You should be able to access the computer's built-in boot manager by hitting Esc, Enter, or (most likely) a function key. Once you boot Windows, download and install [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) and use it to reset the Windows boot loader as the default. Another option is to use an emergency disk (like the Ubuntu installer) to remove the `EFI/ubuntu/` directory tree from the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)

Comment: @TonyLancer .. I've usb but the only pc doesn't boot. And don't have bootable ubuntu....

Comment: @RodSmith Thanks but hitting esc also didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem once and got resolved using this article:

[Repair Linux boot failures in GRUB 2 rescue mode](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/)